# Workaround for "Formula omits adjacent cells"

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, with the following function:

```
=IF(AND(N3=1,ISNUMBER(D3),ISNUMBER(E3)),SUM(D3:E3)-2,IF(AND(N3=1,D3="",E3=""),G3,IF(N3=1,"",IF(AND(N3=0,ISNUMBER(D3)),D3-1,IF(AND(N3=0,ISNUMBER(E3)),E3-1,IF(AND(N3=0,D3="",E3=""),G3,IF(N3="","",G3)))))))
```

I get the error:

> Formula omits adjacent cells

How can I fix the formula to avoid getting the error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error you are getting means that there are cells near the ones in your formula that are of a similar format and Excel thinks that you might have missed them by accident. For example, if you had

```
    A
1 87
2 76
3 109
4 65
```

then the formula

```
=SUM(A1:A3)
```

would give a similar error. So, without seeing your source data, it is difficult to answer your question. I would recommend updating the formula as it suggests and then seeing if it then includes all the cells you want. If it doesn't, just undo and ignore the error.

Answer (score 3):

Just use absolute cell references with the `$` sign and this warning will go away:

> $A$1 instead of A1

Answer (score 0):

If the cell range you specify is what you intended, i.e. you do want to deliberately exclude certain cells, for example a blank row or column (or even just one cell or more), you can effectively "tell" Excel to ignore those cells by changing their format to *text*.  Excel knows then to not try to include them.